# How to add horizontal threshold lines after data is loaded?

Tags: highcharts

I have case where I am plotting time series data of temperature and humidity. This data comes with some upper & lower thresholds. These thresholds depend upon type of equipment I am looking at. These threshold values can be returned as part of JSON request that returns the JSON data to be plotted. Now the question is how do I programatically set the horizontal line that would indicate these thresholds.

Asked other way how to I set values for yAxis.plotLines once the data is loaded? Is there an example that shows how that is done? Even if its not yAxis.plotLines any other example of how to set chart options once the data is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically add a plot line after render time you can use [`Axis.addPlotLine(options)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine), as shown here:

```
// Add plotline when you have the data you need
chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
    value : 7.5,
    color : 'green',
    dashStyle : 'shortdash',
    width : 2,
    label : {
        text : 'My PlotLine'
    }
});
```

Here we are grabbing the y-axis through our `chart` variable and just feeding in regular plotline options to the `addPlotLine` function. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87H3R/) for a live demonstration.

If necessary those same plotlines can be removed with [`Axis.removePlotLine(id)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine), if you supplied a ID in the  options when you added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your json and in preprocessing find a two values which plotLines should be used, return to variable and then use in axis option.